# "QtQuick.LocalStorage" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

i'm using localStorage for saving user Settings :

```
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
```

i get this error while compiling it :

> module "QtQuick.LocalStorage" is not installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Removed Content of Debug Folder and then 'run Qmake' and then Build was successful and no errors at all (i changed to 5.11 and 5.8 with no result)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu-based systems install the missing dependency with:

```
sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-localstorage
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Swapping kits to the 5.6.3 one resolves this error.

Comment: problem is when i create a new project in qtcreator with ``import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0`` there is no problem its working! but with same 5.10.1 which i'm using i got that error, project is really big i cant make another project

Comment: After testing, i just swapped back to 5.11.2 and it compiled correctly. i'm really not sure what is causing this one.